# Update Google Play Services. App won't work unless you update google play services

Tags: android, firebase, firebaseui

I've been trying to run an app on my **Android Emulator** and this error message is displayed when I launch the `activity`. I'm presently using **Nexus 5x x86_64** API 25 and I've tried many different emulator with different configuration. I've installed system images, made changes to the play services version and also updated all the `SDK` tools. Nothing has worked. And I can't use a physical device because I don't have one. This started only after I added the `Firebase UI`. Can anyone help me solve this error?

My app build.gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'


    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Hi Mohit
I would like to suggest you to use the genymotion. There is a personal use version that is freely available for lifetime.

Comment: what error you are facing

Comment: @NileshRathod It's the title. "Update Google Play Services. App won't run unless you update google play services".

Comment: @ShravanJain Thanks I can try, but if it has any learning curve, then I don't have so much time.

Comment: nothing is there to learn.. you just download that software and it will start working on your system..it's very easy :)

Comment: @ShravanJain Thank you. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing this message because you are using an emulator which by default does not have any google play service installed. Because Firebase is a part of google play service, which is not compiling while you running the app. To get it working, you may apply the below solution...

1. Either you can remove Firebase UI
2. Use real device which have google play store account
3. Either install Xamarin Android Player / Genymotion and then install play service on them manually to work.

I have attached a link of tutorial [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8rlAk4TIXQ&feature=youtu.be) of installing google play store in Xamarin Android Player. Hope it helps.

Comment: But when I use the firebase database, it works fine. Why does this happen for firebase UI?

Comment: @MohitMotwani i have not checked with Firebase Database. But it should not work as well. If it is working, then i have to check.